# Copy file from UNIX server to Local Desktop

Tags: java, unix, server

Can some please tell me how to connect UNIX server(EX: apsf2221). I need copy file from unix server to our local desktop

```
    String SFTPHOST = "apsf2221";
    int SFTPPORT = 22;
    String SFTPUSER = "abc001";
    String SFTPPASS = "abc123";
    String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/batchroot/XML/prod2/status_archive/*.txt";
```

When I connect to the server I am getting the error below.

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /batchroot/XML/prod2/status_archive/*.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Code:

```
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show what you do with the variable `SFTPWORKINGDIR`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the specific code that is throwing the exception. Does "/batchroot/XML/prod2/status_archive/*.txt" name an actual file? Or are you expecting some kind of wildcard matching to take place?